# Ordered associations

Tags: associations

*Mathematica* 10 has introduced Associations, elsewhere known as hash tables or dictionaries. Is there Ordered equivalent like in Python, Java, .NET? The data structure should remember the order in which key-value is inserted.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Associations ***are*** ordered.

Comment: @Leonid Shifrin, any reference? I could not find.

Comment: Apparently, this seems to not be mentioned in the docs explicitly, at least not on the main `Association` doc page. One can sort of figure this out by the fact that one can use `Part` with numerical indices on associations, but such fundamental property should be mentioned explicitly. I will file a suggestion report.

Comment: Not exactly a reference, but `Sort` and `KeySort` return sorted associations (and that's documented behavior). That wouldn't make *any* sense if associations were unordered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That associations are ordered can be easily demonstrated.

```
assoc = <|a -> x, b -> y, c -> z|>;

assoc[d] = 42; assoc
```

> ```
> <|a -> x, b -> y, c -> z, d -> 42|>
> ```

```
assoc[a] = w; assoc
```

> ```
> <|a -> w, b -> y, c -> z, d -> 42|>
> ```

Since the key `d` did not exist, the key, value pair `d -> 42` was added to the end of the association. On the hand since the key `a` did exist, it's position was preserved.

Comment: `assoc = <|b -> x, c -> y, d -> z|>;  assoc[a] = 42; assoc (* <|b -> x, c -> y, d -> z, a -> 42|> *)`, so order in `Association` means insertion order, as opposed to the infinite universe of orders (reflexive, antisymmetric relation) that one might imagine, eg lex order.

Comment: @m_goldberg, is this guaranteed behavior? You did not show operations such as deletion of key-value pairs

Comment: @denfromufa. I can't *guarantee* any behavior, but all the ways I know of that can delete a pair preserve the order. Obviously some operations, such as `Sort`, `KeySort`, etc., don't preserve order because their purpose is to change it. I would recommend that you just try any operation you are suspicious of and see what happens. _Mathematica_ is so interactive that is trivial to make such experiments.

Answer (score 1):

The *fast introduction for programmers* on [associations](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/associations/) with additional notes for Python:

> NOTES FOR PYTHON PROGRAMMERS:
>
> **Associations** in the Wolfram Language work similarly to Python dictionaries. Using an **Association**, programmers can associate keys to values with highly efficient lookup and updating, even with millions of elements, and they also *preserve the order of element insertion without needing* specialized data structures like Python's **OrderedDict**. When coding in Python with the [**Wolfram Client Library for Python**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/), classes like **dict**, **OrderedDict** and **Series** (from the **Pandas** library) serialize to Association.

To be precise Python 3.7 (2018) maintains insertion order for dicts as well:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects